# Radius Apache web server on centos

Tags: apache, bash, centos, radius

Hey guys i am having a big problem , i have a centos vps and and i want radius apache web server Authentication. but in these tutorial http://freeradius.org/mod_auth_radius/ , i do not know where i should enter this :

```
./configure --add-module=LOCATION/mod_auth_radius.c
```

( i tried that in "var/www" and "etc/httpd" but show me these error :  -bash: ./configure: No such file or directory )
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to run ./configure from your Apache source, wherever you built Apache from.  Since it sounds like you're new to building stuff, I wouldn't recommend that you build Apache from source.

On Centos 7, I did the following to build it.  First, I had to install a couple of packages for Apache development:

```
sudo yum -y install httpd-devel
sudo yum -y install openssl
sudo yum -y install openssl-devel
```

Then to build it I did:

```
cd /tmp
tar xvf mod_auth_radius-1.5.8.tar
cd mod_auth_radius-1.5.8
cp mod_auth_radius-2.{0,4}.c
sed s/remote_ip/client_ip/g -i mod_auth_radius-2.4.c
apxs -i -a -c mod_auth_radius-2.4.c
```

The sed it because the code doesn't compile right on Apache 2.4.

There, now you have a /etc/httpd/modules/mod_auth_radius-2.4.so ready to go.